# Invalid Content-Length is sent to the server?

Tags: java, android, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to upload a photo to the popular service Dailybooth via their new API through the method [documented here](http://developers.dailybooth.com/pictures).

The problem is that the server is responding with:

```
<html><head><title>411 Length Required</title>...
```

The code I'm using to send this data is here:

```
// 2: Build request
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
SharedPreferences settings = DailyboothShared.getPrefs(DailyboothTakePhoto.this);
String oauth_token = settings.getString("oauth_token", "");
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
        "https://api.dailybooth.com/v1/pictures.json?oauth_token=" + oauth_token);
Log.d("upload", "Facebook: " + facebook);
Log.d("upload", "Twitter: " + twitter);
try {
    InputStream f = getContentResolver().openInputStream(snap_url);
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    entity.addPart("picture", new InputStreamBody(f, snap_url.getLastPathSegment()));
    entity.addPart("blurb", new StringBody(blurb));
    entity.addPart("publish_to[facebook]", new StringBody(facebook));
    entity.addPart("publish_to[twiter]", new StringBody(twitter));
    httppost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    Log.d("upload", response.toString());
    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode == 200) {
        // do something?
    } else {
        Log.d("upload", "Something went wrong :/");
    }
    Log.d("upload", EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've got no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using either `StringBody` and `InputStreamBody` classes which describe the content of your MultipartEntity. Looking at the sources, `StringBody.getContentLength()` returns the length of the string, but `InputStreamBody` always return `-1`, and I guess this is done for the case you need to upload some data to the server without knowing the size of it, and start uploading while data comes to the stream.

If you want to be able to set the content length then you need to know the size of your stream beforehand, what you can do if that's the case is to set the `InputStreamBody` that way:

```
new InputStreamBody(f, snap_url.getLastPathSegment()) {

    public long getContentLength() {
        return /*your length*/;
    }
}
```

or dump your stream in a `byte[]` array and pass `ByteArrayInputStream` to the `InputStreamBody`, of course doing so you loose the streaming ability as you need to cache your data in memory before sending it over...

As you said you are working on images, are this images `File` by any chance? If so you also have `FileBody` that return the correct `content-length`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try these suggestions. Unfortuantly I've tried to easily get a "File" object, although the Android system doesn't want me to be able to do this.

Comment: How come you can't read file? I'm pretty sure you can do so on android as java.io.File is part of the SDK. it could be some permission problem maybe

Comment: I'm trying to get the file from a camera and other applications, which returned the url as "content://blah/blah/blah" which for some reason File doesn't open. However, I changed to use File Descriptors which allow me to "Stat" the length and it worked. Thanks :D